# jQuery wrap code after x number of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a UL that contain any number of LIs. I am trying to create some jQuery code that will parse the original UL and wrap a UL and another LI after every 5 of the original LIs.

**Starting HTML:**

```
<ul id="original_ul">
    <li class="original_li">..</li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
</ul>
```

**Required HTML:**

```
<ul id="processed_ul">

    <li class="new_wrap_li">

        <ul class="new_wrap_ul">

            <li class="original_li">..</li>
            <li>..</li>
            <li>..</li>
            <li>..</li>
            <li>..</li>

        </ul><!-- end new wrap ul -->

    </li><!-- end new wrap li -->

    <li class="new_wrap_li">

        <ul class="new_wrap_ul">

            <li class="original_li">..</li>
            <li>..</li>
            <li>..</li>
            <li>..</li>
            <li>..</li>

        </ul><!-- end new wrap ul -->

    </li><!-- end new wrap li -->

</ul><!-- end processed ul -->
```

I've been using the .each function to go through the LIs and append them to the new processed ul held inside a temp div... now I just need to wrap the new LI and UL around every 5 LIs.

Thanks in advance!!

Al

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var lis = $("#original_ul li");
for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i+=5) {
  lis.slice(i, i+5)
     .wrapAll("<li class='new_wrap_li'><ul class='new_wrap_ul'></ul></li>");
}
```

This keeps them in the same `#original_ul` element, but you could just change the ID if that's necessary.  This approach generates the exact output html you have in the question aside from the ID on the top `<ul>`

Comment: Wow, this was my first posting ever on stackoverflow and I never imagined receiving so many helpful responses!! Thanks a lot everyone! I went with Nick's solution as it seems the simplest and I don't even need my temp div anymore - I just perform the actions directly on the orginal list. Thanks a lot mate!!

Answer (score 4):

```
jQuery('ul#original_ul').attr('id', 'processed_ul')
    .find('li:nth-child(5n)').each(function() {
        $(this).prevAll('li').andSelf()
            .wrapAll('<li class="new_wrap_li"><ul class="new_wrap_ul"></ul></li>');
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a loop.

For example: (Untested)

```
while($('ul#original li').length) {
    var newContainer = $('<li class="new_wrap_li"><ul class="new_wrap_ul" /></li>')
        .appendTo('#processed_ul');


    $('ul#original li:lt(4)').detach().appendTo(newContainer.children('ul'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do it:

```
$('#original_ul').find('li:nth-child(5n)').each(function(){
    $(this).prevAll('li').andSelf()
        .wrapAll('<ul class="new_wrap_ul"></ul>');
}).end().find('ul').wrap('<li class="new_wrap_li"></li>')
.find('li:first-child').addClass('original_li');
```