# How do I wrap a repeatbale set of elements in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, set, selection, traversal

In jQuery how would I go about wrapping a repeatable set of elements with a div?

For example I have:

```
img
h4
p  
img
h4
p
img
h4
p
```

I need to wrap each `img`, `h4`, `p` set with a `div class="container"`. So it will look like:

```html
<div class="container"> img h4 p </div>
<div class="container"> img h4 p </div>
<div class="container"> img h4 p </div>
```

I keep getting nested `div.containers`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var elems = $("#content").find("img, h4, p");
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i+=3) {
  elems.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='container'></div>");
}
```

This works by selecting the container these elements are in and grabbing this specific types, if the elements you want are everything, you can replace [`.find(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) with [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), in this case I used this for the parent element:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/NTmfW/1/)

Comment: @karim - Had the slight advantage of answering this a few times ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485479/jquery-wrap-code-after-x-number-of-elements

Comment: haha sorry I didnt even see that previous question! Thanks heaps man and thanks for showing me the jsfiddle site thats awesome.

Comment: @Globalz - Make sure to accept answers via the check-mark beside the one that helped, makes your questions much more appealing to would-be answerers :)

Comment: Your too helpful! LOL Thanks dude I gave you the green tick!

Answer (score 0):

Your example is pretty simple, so this will work:

```
$("h4").each(function () {
  $(this).prev().andSelf().next().andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='container'/>");
});
```

[demo here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/bEpZy/)

Comment: That's a **lot** of traversing for doing something that can be much faster, `$("img").each(function() { $(this).nextUntil("img").andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='container'></div>"); });` for example.

Comment: Didn't know about `nextUntil` (can you tell I don't do DOM traversal in jQuery much?).  Great improvement :)